# Android-check if the record exists or not

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm new to Android SQLite. I've created the table name "Registration":

```
id FirstName LastName UserName Password Mobile
0  Rakesh     L        rocky   pw123    9600956892
1  Ramesh     S        ram     wckt123  9600634845
2  Vignesh    A        vicky   vky123   9380930489
3  Balaji     B        bala    ball123  9597735613
```

If I register again with the same username and password, it must show the Toast. 
I've tried the following snippet .But i failed to succeed.

```
  DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE username=? AND password=?", new String[]{username,password});
            if (mCursor != null) {
                if(mCursor.getCount()!=0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
         return false;
}
```

Please help me with code snippets.

Comment: db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE username='"+ username +"' AND password='"+ password+"'", null);

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

You just check **Cursor not null** after that why you *check* **count not 0**.

So, that you try this...

```
DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE    username=? AND password=?", new String[]{username,password});

if (mCursor != null)
{
                return true;
    /* record exist */
}
else
{
            return false;
    /* record not exist */
}
```

Comment: Well, count not 0 is actually necessary. On not existing rows the cursor is not null, so this is not enough.

Comment: Although I'm using query instead of rawQuery, maybe that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Check using Cursor as below:

```
Cursor c = <YourDatabase>.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE+ " WHERE " + FIELD + "= '" + VALUE + "'");
if(c == null)
{
  //doesn't exists therefore insert record.
}
```